# Reference request: Indecomposable representations of posets

Tags: representation-theory, order-theory

Let $I$ be a finite poset.

**Definition:** A *representation* of $I$ is a functor $I\to\mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbb C}\ $. Equivalently, a representation of $I$ is a module over its [incidence algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra) $\mathbb C I$.

The posets of finite representation type have been determined by Michèle Loupias in the very brief paper [Indecomposable representations of finite ordered sets](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0081225).

**Request:** Is there a more comprehensive discussion of finite representation type posets (ideally including explicit descriptions of indecomposable representations) somewhere in the literature?

---

There is a related but different notion called *matrix representation* in [Daniel Simson: Linear representations of partially ordered sets and vector space categories](https://books.google.de/books/about/Linear_representations_of_partially_orde.html?id=RnStnI4GMQsC&redir_esc=y):

**Definition:** A *matrix representation* of $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ (equipped with a partial order $\preceq$) consists of vector spaces $V_1,\ldots,V_{n+1}$ and linear maps $t_j\colon V_j\to V_{n+1}$ for $J=1,\ldots,n$. A morphism of matrix representations is a commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
    V_1\oplus\cdots\oplus V_n & \xrightarrow{(t_j)} & V_{n+1} \\
    \downarrow &  & \downarrow\\
    V_1'\oplus\cdots\oplus V_n' & \xrightarrow{(t_j')} & V_{n+1}'
\end{array}
$$
in which the map $V_i\to V_j'$ vanishes if $i\not\preceq j$.

The category of matrix representations of $I$ turns out to be equivalent to a full subcategory of the category of $\mathbb C I^*$-modules, where $I^*$ is the poset obtained from $I$ be adding a unique maximal element.

**Question:** Given that the notion of representation is more natural than the notion of matrix representation (at least to me), why are matrix representations so much more prominent in the literature?

Comment: [ http://www-users.mat.umk.pl/~simson/DrozdowskiSimson1978.pdf ] is a short survey that might be useful.

Comment: @Julian Kuelshammer: Thank you for the link. The paper is great in that it lists all posets of finite representation type.